# show/hide div based on slider(checkbox) selection

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to show/hide hiddencar div based on what the slider is on? Im not sure how to use :target selectors and I believe it can be done with css alone

yes show div no hide div

```css
     .onoffswitch4 {
        position: relative; width: 101px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4   {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label4 {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid ; border-radius: 11px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4 {
        display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:before, .onoffswitch-inner4:after {
        display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 38px; padding: 0; line-height: 38px;
        font-size: 13px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:before {
        content: "No";
        padding-left: 14px;
        background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:after {
        content: "Yes";
        padding-right: 14px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch4 {
        display: block; width: 9px; margin: 14.5px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 59px;
        border: 2px solid ; border-radius: 11px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 .onoffswitch-inner4 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 .onoffswitch-switch4 {
        right: 0px; 
    }
```

```html
   <div id="contact_phone">Do you have a car?: *<br>
     <div class="onoffswitch4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch4" class="onoffswitch-checkbox4" id="myonoffswitch4" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label4" for="myonoffswitch4">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner4"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch4"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    
    
<div id="hiddencar">       
    
 <div id="contact_name">Year: *<br>
 <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
    </div> 
 
        
 <div id="contact_phone">Make: *<br>
 <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
 </div>    
      
      
     <div id="contact_phone">Model: *<br>
     <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
    </div>   
     
</div><!--hiddencar-->
    
    
    
   </div><!--contact_phone-->
```

Is there a way to show/hide hiddencar div based on what the slider is on? Im not sure how to use :target selectors and I believe it can be done with css alone

yes show div no hide div

Comment: This will give some inspiration. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp .. use the :checked selector

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to listen to the checkbox and then check its value to hide or show the hidden car div.

First grab the Dom elements.

Second, add an event listener to the checkbox, every time somebody changes the checkbox value it will return a Boolean (true or false) statement and from there you can toggle a hide class

```
const checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=onoffswitch4]')
const hiddenCar = document.getElementById('hiddencar')

checkbox.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.checked) {
    hiddenCar.classList.add('hide')
  } else {
    hiddenCar.classList.remove('hide')
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
#hiddencar {
  display: block;
}

#hiddencar.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**Codepen** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEMEap?editors=0001

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the CSS slider isn't actually changing the checked property of the checkbox, I added this in my JS solution as well as a showHideCarFields function that will reveal or hide the car fields as appropriate

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".onoffswitch4", function() {
    $("#myonoffswitch4").prop("checked", !$("#myonoffswitch4").prop("checked"))
    showHideCarFields();
  });
  showHideCarFields();
});

function showHideCarFields() {
    var isChecked = $('#myonoffswitch4').prop("checked");
    if(isChecked) {
      $('#hiddencar').hide();
    } else {
      $('#hiddencar').show();
    }
}
```

```css
.onoffswitch4 {
        position: relative; width: 101px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4   {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label4 {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid ; border-radius: 11px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4 {
        display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:before, .onoffswitch-inner4:after {
        display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 38px; padding: 0; line-height: 38px;
        font-size: 13px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:before {
        content: "No";
        padding-left: 14px;
        background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:after {
        content: "Yes";
        padding-right: 14px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch4 {
        display: block; width: 9px; margin: 14.5px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 59px;
        border: 2px solid ; border-radius: 11px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 .onoffswitch-inner4 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 .onoffswitch-switch4 {
        right: 0px; 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contact_phone">Do you have a car?: *<br>
     <div class="onoffswitch4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch4" class="onoffswitch-checkbox4" id="myonoffswitch4" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label4" for="myonoffswitch4">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner4"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch4"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    
    
<div id="hiddencar">       
    
 <div id="contact_name">Year: *<br>
 <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
    </div> 
 
        
 <div id="contact_phone">Make: *<br>
 <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
 </div>    
      
      
     <div id="contact_phone">Model: *<br>
     <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
    </div>   
     
</div><!--hiddencar-->
    
    
    
   </div><!--contact_phone-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `hiddencar` element to be immediately after the checkbox label, and then use multiple `+` selectors to select the element after the labels, like the below:

```css
    .onoffswitch4 {
         position: relative; width: 101px;
        -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4   {
        display: none;
    }
    .onoffswitch-label4 {
        display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid ; border-radius: 11px;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4 {
        display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
        transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:before, .onoffswitch-inner4:after {
        display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 38px; padding: 0; line-height: 38px;
        font-size: 13px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:before {
        content: "No";
        padding-left: 14px;
        background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .onoffswitch-inner4:after {
        content: "Yes";
        padding-right: 14px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .onoffswitch-switch4 {
        display: block; width: 9px; height: 9px; margin: 14.5px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
        right: 59px;
        border: 2px solid ; border-radius: 11px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 .onoffswitch-inner4 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 .onoffswitch-switch4 {
        right: 0px; 
    }

    .onoffswitch-checkbox4:checked + .onoffswitch-label4 + #hiddencar {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
   <div id="contact_phone">Do you have a car?: *<br>
     <div class="onoffswitch4">
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch4" class="onoffswitch-checkbox4" id="myonoffswitch4" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label4" for="myonoffswitch4">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner4"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch4"></span>
        </label>
        
       <div id="hiddencar">        
        <div id="contact_name">Year: *<br>
            <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
           </div> 
 
        
        <div id="contact_phone">Make: *<br>
            <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
        </div>    
      
      
            <div id="contact_phone">Model: *<br>
                <input id="element_4" name="name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="50" value="" placeholder="FULL NAME"/>
            </div>   
     
        </div><!--hiddencar-->
    </div>

   </div><!--contact_phone-->
```